# Solr. Strange facet search result

Tags: java, solr

I make this request:

> `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?indent=on&q=*:*&fl=*&facet=true&facet.field=id&rows=99`

and see next result:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">31</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="facet">true</str>
<str name="fl">*</str>
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="q">*:*</str>
<str name="facet.field">id</str>
<str name="rows">99</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="28" start="0">...</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="id">
<int name="0579B002">1</int>
<int name="100-435805">1</int>
<int name="3007WFP">1</int>
<int name="6H500F0">1</int>
<int name="9885A004">1</int>
<int name="EN7800GTX/2DHTV/256M">1</int>
<int name="EUR">1</int>
<int name="F8V7067-APL-KIT">1</int>
<int name="GB18030TEST">1</int>
<int name="GBP">1</int>
<int name="IW-02">1</int>
<int name="MA147LL/A">1</int>
<int name="NOK">1</int>
<int name="SOLR1000">1</int>
<int name="USD">1</int>
<int name="UTF8TEST">1</int>
<int name="VA902B">1</int>
<int name="adata">1</int>
<int name="apple">1</int>
<int name="asus">1</int>
<int name="ati">1</int>
<int name="belkin">1</int>
<int name="canon">1</int>
<int name="corsair">1</int>
<int name="dell">1</int>
<int name="maxtor">1</int>
<int name="samsung">1</int>
<int name="viewsonic">1</int>
<int name="SP2514N">0</int>
<int name="TWINX2048-3200PRO">0</int>
<int name="VDBDB1A16">0</int>
<int name="VS1GB400C3">0</int>
</lst>
</lst>
<lst name="facet_dates"/>
<lst name="facet_ranges"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

I cannot inderstand why I see

```
    <int name="SP2514N">0</int>
    <int name="TWINX2048-3200PRO">0</int>
    <int name="VDBDB1A16">0</int>
    <int name="VS1GB400C3">0</int>
```

What does ot mean?

```
VS1GB400C3  is not matching in all xml document
```

**UPDATE**

request:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?indent=on&q=*&fl=id&rows=9999
```

response:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fl">id</str>
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="q">*</str>
<str name="rows">9999</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="28" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">GB18030TEST</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">6H500F0</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">F8V7067-APL-KIT</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">IW-02</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">MA147LL/A</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">adata</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">apple</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">asus</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">ati</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">belkin</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">canon</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">corsair</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">dell</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">maxtor</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">samsung</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">viewsonic</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">USD</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">EUR</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">GBP</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">NOK</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">3007WFP</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">VA902B</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">0579B002</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">9885A004</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">SOLR1000</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">UTF8TEST</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">EN7800GTX/2DHTV/256M</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">100-435805</str>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

I cannot to copy here all docs examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but semi-informed speculation here…

It's possible that the document this value came from has since been deleted. Lucene deletions and document updates mark old versions of a document as deleted (or tombstoned) without actually rewriting any of the data on the disk.

So an earlier document inserted that term into your index's term dictionary, then was probably updated or deleted. So the term is still in the dictionary, but there are zero current documents which contain it.

Issuing an [optimize](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22) or a commit with `expungeDeletes=true` should get rid of the extraneous terms.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your facet query and results you have an id with VS1GB400C3 . 
Can you post your field definition for id, some example data that were indexed?

Also try queryinf id:VS1GB400C3  see what it finds.

This is custom data , there is no way for others to know unless you explain why you understand some results and do not understand other results. It helps us answer your question with a bit more details of your question.

Comment: Its in your <collection>\conf\sechma.xml file <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />  also check if your is is defined like this : <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

Comment: **<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> **

Comment: it is my configuration

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong. But IIRC facetting returns every unique value for that field (undependend of your query), then it will matches the result of your query and you will get the count from there. So if you only want the facet result that correspond with your query, you should put

```
facet.mincount=1
```

in the query.